# Bug in Android 2.1 in async-thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I'm using `Handler` and `HandlerThread` to perform asynchronous loading in my application, but something is going wrong, for example:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        .....................
    }

}, 100);
```

this handler wrip (sic) in a new HandlerThread and is created in `onCreate()`.

It seems like that is no problem, however there are times when an error appears, one example of this is a `NullPointerException` caused on this handler - it is stable before - but when I test on 2.1 version emulator this happen some times and I can't solve it, is thee any one that can help me?

Comment: Can you provide additional details? On which Android version does it run correctly? 1.6? 2.3? Is this specific to the 2.1? Does it work on devices?

Comment: it works on my phone before ,it is 2.3 .
the emulater is running on 2.1 , it happen many times now .

Comment: the problem is he always have some null pointer exception and i know that value will not have nullpointer , because i have new a instance before and never touch it .

Comment: Have you try on a 2.3 simulator?

Comment: also same result , some where cannot be null , but have nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you considered race conditions in your code? it sounds like the handler code is not performing proper synchonization - and might sometimes see changes from a different thread - which again causes your nullPointer exception.

try wrapping your problem code in a synchonized block - or if you are using primitve types only - move to volatile or atomic types.

Comment: i found it is cause from the handler problem on asynchronize , thnks a lot